# How to rename package in grail

Tags: grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, grails-2.0

I have installed grails support in STS. and I have a grails application inside that I got package com.mycompany.myapp in domain, controllers and tests. I want to rename them to mycompany.myapp, So that It should affect the functionality of application. Is there any way to do it in Grails.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the normal Eclipse refactoring tooling ie <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to move package.

If you're using any inheritance in your domain classes you'll need to upgrade the class name in the `class` column for these tables.

Comment: If it´s a Mac user "Cmd + shift + R" will do it :)